How to draw a heptagon with node at the right positions
could you help me I'm struggling to get a heptagon, here's the best code an AI generated but it failed to obtain a proper heptagone.
Thanks.
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
% Define the heptagon vertices
\node[draw, circle, font=\scriptsize] (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node[draw, circle, font=\scriptsize] (B) at (1.5,0) {B};
\node[draw, circle, font=\scriptsize] (C) at (2.121,1.213) {C};
\node[draw, circle, font=\scriptsize] (D) at (1.5,2.426) {D};
\node[draw, circle, font=\scriptsize] (E) at (0,2.426) {E};
\node[draw, circle, font=\scriptsize] (F) at (-1.5,2.426) {F};
\node[draw, circle, font=\scriptsize] (G) at (-2.121,1.213) {G};

% Draw arrows between adjacent vertices
\draw [->] (A)--(B);
\draw [->] (B)--(C);
\draw [->] (C)--(D);
\draw [->] (D)--(E);
\draw [->] (E)--(F);
\draw [->] (F)--(G);
\draw [->] (G)--(A);

\end{tikzpicture}


Welcome to TeX.SX! You could use polar coordinates to place the nodes.

Since you used AI to come up with a solution, I asked the ducks from the TeX.SX duckpond and they just offered a solution based on the experimental l3draw package (but note that this is not TikZ, so you can't use TikZ styles to style it).
It seems that the first argument takes the number of edges of the polygon, the second argument takes the radius of the circle on which the nodes sit, and the third argument takes the radius of the nodes.
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \Polygon } { m m m } {
    \draw_begin:
        \int_step_inline:nn {#1} {
            \draw_path_moveto:n { 
                \draw_point_intersect_line_circle:nnnnn
                    {
                        \draw_point_polar:nn {#2} { 
                            90 - ( ##1 - 1 ) * 360 / #1 
                        }
                    } {
                        \draw_point_polar:nn {#2} { 
                            90 - ##1 * 360 / #1 
                        }
                    } { 
                        \draw_point_polar:nn {#2} { 
                            90 - ( ##1 - 1 ) * 360 / #1 
                        } 
                    } {#3} { 1 }
            } 
            \draw_path_lineto:n { 
                \draw_point_intersect_line_circle:nnnnn
                    {
                        \draw_point_polar:nn {#2} { 
                            90 - ( ##1 - 1 ) * 360 / #1 }
                    } {
                        \draw_point_polar:nn {#2} { 
                            90 - ##1 * 360 / #1 
                        }
                    } { 
                        \draw_point_polar:nn {#2} { 
                            90 - ##1 * 360 / #1 
                        } 
                    } {#3} { 0 }
            } 
            \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
            \draw_path_circle:nn { 
                \draw_point_polar:nn {#2} { 
                    90 - ( ##1 - 1 ) * 360 / #1 
                } 
            } { #3 }
            \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
            \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_tmpa_coffin { \int_to_Alph:n {##1} }
            \draw_scope_begin:
                \draw_transform_shift:n { 
                    \draw_point_polar:nn {#2} { 
                        90 - ( ##1 - 1 ) * 360 / #1 
                    } 
                }
                \draw_coffin_use:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { hc } { vc } 
            \draw_scope_end:
        }
    \draw_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\Polygon{7}{5em}{1em}

\Polygon{3}{5em}{1em}

\end{document}



For nodes arranged in regular shapes, I usually employ loops. That can be daunting for someone new, but it can really shorten the length of your code. Here is my code:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \b [count=\a] in {%
A,%
B,%
C,%
D,%
E,%
F,%
G%
}{%
\draw (\a*360/7: 4cm) node [circle, draw=black, text width=10mm, align=center] (\a) {\b};}
\draw [draw = black]
(1) edge (2)
(2) edge (3)
(3) edge (4)
(4) edge (5)
(5) edge (6)
(6) edge (7)
(7) edge (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

That will generate the output:


You can use tkz-berge. I'll have to update this package, which is nearly 15 years old.
\documentclass[margin = 12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\begin{document}
\GraphInit[vstyle=Shade]
\SetGraphShadeColor{blue!60!black!30}{blue}{white}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \grCycle[RA=3]{7}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Almost a one-liner with the TikZ shapes.geometric library:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe,
    papersize={5.5in,8.5in},margin=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\tikz{%
    \node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=7,minimum size=2in,draw](H){};%
    \foreach \n [count=\nn from 1] in {A,...,G}\node[draw,circle,fill=white] at (H.corner \nn){\n};
}

\end{document}


